# How do I have a makefile correctly recognize includes in multiple directories

Tags: c, makefile, include, include-path

I have been struggling with having my make file properly compile all of my source files due to an include error at compile time. I have looked at some questions online but the solutions do not seem to fix mine.

I can get this program to compile if I have all of the source files in the same directory but once I tried splitting up the files into separate directories it no longer worked.

**Here is is the error:**

```
~/Documents/GitHub/testing$ make build
gcc -I/. -Wall main.c inplementation/inplementation.c -o program.exe

In file included from main.c:3:
./inplementation/inplementation.h:4:10: fatal error: 'module/module.h' file not found
\#include "module/module.h"

1 error generated.

In file included from inplementation/inplementation.c:1:
inplementation/inplementation.h:4:10: fatal error: 'module/module.h' file not found
\#include "module/module.h"
1 error generated.
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

**Here is a screenshot of my file directory:**

[image: file directory]

**Here is a screenshot of my include paths of this project:**
[image: include paths]

**Here is a screenshot of my make file (specifically build):**
[image: build function in makefile]

Comment: The output you present does not correspond to the Makefile fragment you present.  Instead of random bits and pieces, please construct and present a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  I estimate the you could fit one in about the same amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

You use `#include "module/module.h"` while the include flag is `-I/$(TESTING_DIR)/module`.

First of all I think you probably meant `-I$(TESTING_DIR)/module`, otherwise you are adding an extra slash before the path stored in `TESTING_DIR`.

But the main problem is that `module/module.h` doesn't exist under that `module` folder. So you need to do one of these combinations:

- `-I$(TESTING_DIR)/module` and `#include "module.h"`
- `-I$(TESTING_DIR)` and `#include "module/module.h"`